# Why does SoundPool not automatically route to connected headphones?

Tags: java, android, soundpool

I'm using the [Android SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool) class in order to play UI sounds through my app. The sounds play perfectly when testing on an android device through its integrated speakers, as expected. However, the problem occurs when I connect headphones.

**When I connect wired headphones to the android device, the sound will not route to these headphones. It will continue to play through the integrated speaker of the phone.** The issue persists for Bluetooth headphones.

To ensure that my headphones and device were working properly:

- I ensured that my headphones had correctly routed to other apps. For example, I played music through the headphones on Spotify and then returned to my app, where the audio switched to playing through the integrated speakers.
- I tested this on multiple android devices with the same result.

I was under the impression that audio routing would be automatically handled outside the scope of my application. The Android Developer website has [a section about handling audio](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones), however it does not mention anything about manually routing audio when devices are connected.

### SoundPool Implementation

Here is the relevant code from setting up my SoundPool in a class entitled SoundManager.

I have used a singleton implementation so that I can reference this class from different activities without having to create a new instance each time.

```java
/*
Audio Settings
*/
private final int MAX_STREAMS = 1;
private final int SRC_QUALITY = 1;
private final int STREAM_TYPE = AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA;

/*
Audio Attributes
*/
private final int ATT_USAGE = AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME;
private final int ATT_FLAG = AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED;
private final int ATT_CONTENT = AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION;


private SoundManager() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(ATT_USAGE)
                    .setFlags(ATT_FLAG)
                    .setContentType(ATT_CONTENT)
                    .build();

            soundPlayer = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(MAX_STREAMS)
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                    .build();

        } else {
            soundPlayer = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, STREAM_TYPE, SRC_QUALITY);
        }

        this.audioManager = (AudioManager) appActivity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        appActivity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }

    /*
    Singleton implementation.
     */
    public static synchronized SoundManager get(Context context, AppCompatActivity activity) {
        if (soundManager == null) {
            soundManager = new SoundManager(context, activity);
        }

        return soundManager;
    }

    /* Play A Loaded Clip */
    public void play(SoundElement element) {
        if (existsInLoadedClips(element)) {
            int localId = element.getLocalId();
            float volume = getVolume();

            soundPlayer.play(localId, volume, volume,
                    PRIORITY, LOOP, RATE);
        }
    }
```

This is not the entire class, but is all the pieces that interact with my SoundPool instance.

#### Stream Type

I thought the likely source of the issue was the stream type:

```java
private final int STREAM_TYPE = AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA;
private final int ATT_USAGE = AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME;
```

However, no matter what stream type I used the problem persisted.

#### Volume Control Stream

Secondly, I thought the volume control stream would be related to the issue:

```java
appActivity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

However, I couldn't find a solution by changing this either.

#### Reducing Problem To Basics

In order to eliminate possible sources of the issue, I set up a new project using only a SoundPool object and [a barebones UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylwe7.png).

Using the below code, one can recreate the issue with any sound file:

```java
    Button myBtn;
    SoundPool soundPlayer;

    /*
    Audio Settings
     */
    private final int MAX_STREAMS = 1;
    private final int SRC_QUALITY = 1;
    private final int STREAM_TYPE = AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME;
    /*
    Audio Attributes
     */
    private final int ATT_USAGE = AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME;
    private final int ATT_FLAG = AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED;
    private final int ATT_CONTENT = AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION;

    /*
    Playback Settings
     */
    private final int PRIORITY = 1;
    private final int LOOP = 0;
    private final int RATE = 1;

    int clipId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Create Our SoundPool Object */
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(ATT_USAGE)
                    .setFlags(ATT_FLAG)
                    .setContentType(ATT_CONTENT)
                    .build();

            soundPlayer = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setMaxStreams(MAX_STREAMS)
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                    .build();

        } else {
            soundPlayer = new SoundPool(MAX_STREAMS, STREAM_TYPE, SRC_QUALITY);
        }

        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        /*Find Button & Load A Clip */
        myBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        myBtn.setOnClickListener(new ButtonListener());
        this.clipId = loadClip();
    }

    public int loadClip() {
        String fileName = "your_audio_file";
        String resourceFolder = "raw";

        int resId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(
                fileName, resourceFolder, this.getPackageName());

        int localId = soundPlayer.load(this, resId, 1);

        return localId;
    }

    private void playSound() {
        soundPlayer.play(clipId, 1, 1,
                PRIORITY, LOOP, RATE);
    }

    private class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound();
        }
    }
```

In this bare-bones example, the audio clip will still only play through the integrated speaker of my android devices when the button is pressed and headphones are connected.

I can't seem to find the source of this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Let me know if I can provide any more detail as regards to the code or problem.
I attempted to include everything which I thought relevant, however perhaps more information is needed.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  I'm having a similar issue where I want the SoundPool to only play over the internal speaker, but instead it plays over the internal speaker and connected BT speaker.  
  
One thing I do see is that you are setting the volume on the assumption it will be STREAM_MUSIC.  However audioAttributes.getVolumeControlStream() will dictate what the correct volume control stream is.

Comment: Unfortunately I never solved this problem I had with SoundPool, so I ended up reprogramming the audio classes to use [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer). Thankfully though, there were no such problems when I moved to MediaPlayer and it worked out fine. Thanks for the tip with regards to the volume control stream. I had indeed messed around with that quite a bit to no luck. It's a pity I can't be of more help to you, other than to suggest trying out the MediaPlayer class instead :)

Comment: I can confirm problems with audio routing to headsets (I've tested Bluetooth SCO) when using `SoundPool`... I've also switched to `MediaPlayer`, it have own issues (mostly due to not so convenient architecture), but at least this player may be routed to headset